# Why is my flexbox creating a long, thin line and not three boxes?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a landing page for The Odin Project.

I have, so far, created three flexbox divs; one for the top background-color, a second for the header logo, and the third for three colored boxes where I am going to place my text.

The problem I am having is that instead of three colored boxes being made, I have one long line on my screen which I assume is the border.

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #1F2937;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.header_logo {
  /* background-color:red;
    border: black solid 2px; */
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Keeps one line header and not 2 lines */
}

.header_boxes div {
  background: peachpuff;
  border: 4px solid brown;
  height: 80px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header_logo">
    <h1>Header Logo</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="header_boxes">
    <div class="one">

    </div>
    <div class="two">

    </div>
    <div class="three">

    </div>

  </div>
```

This is what i have: [My website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBWiL.png)

Comment: You're missing a closing `</div>` in your HTML, and you have no content in your boxes therefore they have no width; add content then you get visible boxes: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d7893sa6/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add content to your .header_boxes div's and set the .header_boxes class display property to flex as well to achieve the layout I'm pretty sure you're after.

```
.header_boxes {dispay:flex}
```

Here's a codepen for you to compare against your code: https://codepen.io/conradqq-the-reactor/pen/XWqKENp

Comment: Just add the content you want to see instead of using random, arbitrary sizes (assuming you want to have content in there), unless they're merely presentational. In which case you'd be better using CSS.

Comment: @ConRadQ I have a new issue now. The boxes now have width, but they are stuck together and stacked on top of each other. I set the flex boxes to be rows, and theyre still on top of each other. Also when i use gap in the parent div, they dont get spaced apart. Any idea on why row and gap arent working?

Comment: @jarvic1207 You need to set your header_boxes class as display:flex as well. Currently, only your entire header has display:flex, flex-direction:row. Here's a working code pen to look at: https://codepen.io/conradqq-the-reactor/pen/XWqKENp . If this answers your question please select my reply as the answer :) It will be my first one lol.

Comment: I thought that if you applied display: flex to the parent div, every div under it would also inherit it.

Comment: @jarvic1207 Generally, the default display value of most HTML elements is block or inline, regardless of what the parent's display value is.